expectation of logarithm of scaled chi-squared random variable
Suppose $x_1,\dots, x_n\sim N(0,1)$ are iid Gaussians, and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n > 0$ are positive scalars. Define scaled chi-squared random variable $Y = \sum_i^n \lambda_i x_i^2,$ where we can assume that lambdas are normalized $\sum_i\lambda_i = 1. $ Question: what is the expectation of its logarithm $E \log(Y)$?
It is obvious that since $\lambda_i$'s are normalized, we can lower/upper bound this quantity with the minimum or maximum $\lambda_i$. However, I am trying to approximate, or calculate the expectation more accurately. If this doesn't have a simple answer, what about the case when $n$ is sufficiently large?
